# Unicode error U+308

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I keep getting the following error and I am not sure how to correct it.

[image: Errro message]

These are the packages I have loaded:

```
\usepackage{graphicx, setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

and I am not sure how to fix it. Please can someone advise.

Comment: You need to retype the ü in your bib. It seems to be an u + combining accent, pdftex can't handle this. And delete the bbl and call bibtex again.

Comment: This is probably because the ü in “Büyükasikoglu” (sorry, I am currently unable to type Turkish diacritics) is not encoded as one Unicode codepoint (U+00FC) but as two codepoints (U+0075 U+0308). You should delete the first ü and replace it with a proper ü.

Comment: In your bib file, replace `Büyükaşıkoğlu` with `B{\"u}y{\"u}ka{\c s}{\i}ko{\u g}lu` and run a  full recompile cylcle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.